Qwen-VL Data Preparation code : Is there any similar code for data preparation?
Is there any available code for data preparation?
They have mentioned in the GitHub page. I need to create this format of data for English (not Chinese).
[
  {
    "id": "identity_0",
    "conversations": [
      {
        "from": "user",
        "value": "你好"
      },
      {
        "from": "assistant",
        "value": "我是Qwen-VL,一个支持视觉输入的大模型。"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "identity_1",
    "conversations": [
      {
        "from": "user",
        "value": "Picture 1: <img>https://qianwen-res.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/Qwen-VL/assets/demo.jpeg</img>\n图中的狗是什么品种？"
      },
      {
        "from": "assistant",
        "value": "图中是一只拉布拉多犬。"
      },
      {
        "from": "user",
        "value": "框出图中的格子衬衫"
      },
      {
        "from": "assistant",
        "value": "<ref>格子衬衫</ref><box>(588,499),(725,789)</box>"
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    "id": "identity_2",
    "conversations": [
      {
        "from": "user",
        "value": "Picture 1: <img>assets/mm_tutorial/Chongqing.jpeg</img>\nPicture 2: <img>assets/mm_tutorial/Beijing.jpeg</img>\n图中都是哪"
      },
      {
        "from": "assistant",
        "value": "第一张图片是重庆的城市天际线，第二张图片是北京的天际线。"
      }
    ]
  }
]

Or is there any similar code or GitHub link that I can follow for data preparation for Qwen-VL?
